# Arduino buttons moving in lock step

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino project (it's actually with the Mintduino, but it's the same microcontroller) that has three buttons, setup like the tutorial (http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ButtonStateChange) with a common + and - between them. The buttons are individually connected to A0, A1, and A2. Here is the code I use to read them:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("b1: ");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(A0));
  Serial.print("  b2: ");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(A1));
  Serial.print("  b3: ");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(A2));
  Serial.println("");
}
```

When button are unpressed, I get:

b1: 1  b2: 1  b3: 1

And when I press *any* button, I get:

b1: 0  b2: 0  b3: 0

So I can only tell that a button was pressed, and can not tell which button it was that was pressed. How can I tell one button press from another?

I think I know why it's happening, but I can't think of a solution that doesn't involve using three different batteries so I can get individual circuits.

Comment: Your code is fine. There is probably something wrong with your circuit, but you haven't explained it in enough detail to tell what it is.

Comment: You mention three buttons, but not three resistors. If you just add  extra switches to that circuit without extra pull-down resistors, then pressing any button will connect all the inputs to +5V. You are better using the internal pull-ups and connecting the three switches to ground instead, as Udo Klien says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you got the wiring wrong. Or your code does not match your wiring.

First you should not use A0, A1, A2 but digital pins. Notice that A0, A1, A2 double as digital pins but with different numbers.

So most probably you are reading different pins that the pins you expect to read.

The next thing is that you might be missing pull up / pull down resistors. Unfortunately the tutorial sucks. It does not tell you about the internal pull up resistors which would allow to ditch the external resistor described in the tutorial.

If it is the way I suspect, then you pins are floating and picking up random noise. This can have any number of symptoms including the symptoms you describe. I suggest you extend your code to read all DIGITAL pins from 0 to 19 and see how it reacts to button pushes. Then you will know the proper pin numbers.

In case no pin reacts as desired you most probably got your wiring wrong.